# Drawing an ellipse and changing its orientation

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm new to Photoshop, and currently using Photoshop CC. I'm trying to do the following:

- Draw an ellipse
- Making the ellipse diagonal

How can I do that?

Comment: ...Seriously? Maybe its cause I haven't had my coffee yet but go figure it out. This doesn't warrant a question or even a manual. Play with the different tools, get familiar with them, and you should have this on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you will select layer with your ellipse and Ctrl+T you will see controls for changing size as well as arbitrary rotation. Play with it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Yes, Ctrl+T gave me the options I need. The issue remaining here is that when I first draw the ellipse, and then, try to rotate it or move it for instance, I get a `white` ellipse which is the original one drawn. Why is that? Thanks

Comment: I noticed that I have to make a new layer first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to *Transform* the ellipse shape. The accepted answer refers to the shortcut of *Transform Path,* which can also be found in *edit → Transform Path.*
Here you have the options selecting between specific transform actions like *scale, rotate, skew, warp,* etc. 
For your case you will can use the *rotate* option, which will let you rotate the shape as you like. Once your shape is selected for transform, you can also switch between transform modes easily with right-clicking and selecting the desired transform mode.